# How to create a page that finds if user inputs exists in a file?

Tags: javascript, php, html

Let's say I want to create a web page where users can inputs information and the page will see if that information exists in a file and then displays it to the user. This information could be an email address or a password or anything. Can this be done just with Javascript?

Answer (score 0):

The front-end side can be JavaScript AJAX requesting system which will contact the server and server will process the request and give the answer to the AJAX request and display the results in real time to the user.(just as search engines do)

Only using JavaScript would be hard,as the server side requires to do a search through the given text.

The server side can use some basic string searching.

Answer (score 0):

/*HTML and jQuery*/

```
<input type="text" id="txtInputStr"/>
<button type="button" id="btnFind"/>
<script>
$("#btnFind").on("click",function(){
var postData = [];
postData.push({name:'inputstr',value:$("#txtInputStr").val()});
$.ajax({
type:'post',
url:'findMe.php',
data:postData,
success:function(json)
{
var obj = $.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(json));
console.log(obj.success);
}
})

});
</script>
```

/*php findMe.php*/

```
<?php
$contents = file_get_contents($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $your_file_name);

$res = array("success"=>false;);
if(strpos($contents,$_POST['inputstr']) !== false)
{
$res['success'] = true;
}

echo json_encode($res);
```

where your_file_name is your file name where you want to search.

Comment: Did you forget to put the onlick attribute for the button so the botton actually leads to findMe.php?

Comment: $("#btnFind").on("click",function(){} this line my friend leads to the ajax call for findme.php